# Dynamic loading of CSV file

Tags: sql, csv

The contents of the control file I have is:

```
load data
infile 'C:\Win_20130609.csv'
TRUNCATE INTO table records_temp
 fields terminated by ',' optionally  enclosed by '"' trailing nullcols
(
  SAVINGS_ACCOUNT, 
  BANK_BRANCH

)
```

As it can be seen it has a date. Now I want to load the data dynamically as and when the date keeps changing.

I tried 'Win_*.csv' it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Put the name of the data file on the command line, not in the control file.  See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_params.htm#g1014550 for command line options.

Then, call it passing it whatever filename you want.

Comment: Gary please tell me again. I did not get it. Thanks

Comment: Instead of a filename hardcoded inside the control file, make it a command-line parameter.  Then however you call it can pass the changing filename.  i.e. if you are on a UNIX-like system, you could have a shell script that looks for the file on a schedule and if found passes it as a parameter to SQL*Loader.